Загруженные изображения отображаются только после перезапуска Tomcat
Загружаю изображение через file в jsp странице. При нажатии на странице на кнопку "отправить" название изображения сохраняю в бд, а изображение в папку E:\MyIdeaProjects\CarSale\src\main\webapp\images, открываю index.jsp.
index.jsp отображает изображения из бд. Но загруженные отображает только после Update classes and resources в tomcat. Работаю в intellij. Как исправить, чтобы отображал сразу без перезагрузки tomcat?
Если нужно, то вот код добавления изображения:
Part file=request.getPart("image");
        String imageFileName= file.getSubmittedFileName();
        System.out.println("Название изображения:" + imageFileName);

        //Добавление авто

        if (imageFileName!="")
        {
            String uploadPath ="E:/MyIdeaProjects/CarSale/src/main/webapp/images/"+imageFileName;
            System.out.println("Путь: " + uploadPath);
            try
            {
                FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(uploadPath);
                InputStream is =file.getInputStream();

                byte[]data=new byte [is.available()];

                is.read(data);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        Car car = new Car(title, yearOfIssue, capacity, fuelType, fuelConsumption, gearboxType, power, price, imageFileName);
        CarDB.insert(car);

